# Multicolumn doesn't work well with onslide

Tags: beamer, multicol, overlays

I have the following code which works without error:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
  \onslide<1->{a & b & c & d}
  \onslide<2->{
    \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 1}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 2 left}
    & Line 2 right
  }
  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I changed `Line 2 right`to `\multicolumn{2}{l}{Line 2 right}`, it didn't compile anymore. Then I removed `onslide<2->`, it compiled again, but without overlays effect. So it seems that the 3rd `multicoulmn` does not work well with `onslide`, does anyone know how to solve it?

```
...
\onslide<2->{
  \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 1}
  \\
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 2 left}
  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Line 2 right} \\\hline
}
\onslide<3->{
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 1}
  \\ 
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 2 left}
  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Line 2 right} \\\hline
}
```

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\\` (and `\hline`) at the end of the row inside `\onslide`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
  \onslide<1->{a & b & c & d}
  \onslide<2->{
    \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 1}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 2 left}
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Line 2 right} \\\hline
  }
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, read Section **23.5 Uncovering a Table Rowwise** of the `beamer` manual; a little excerpt

> When you wish to uncover a table line-by-line, you will run into all
>   sorts of problems if there are vertical and horizontal lines in the
>   table. The reason is that the first vertical line at the left end is
>   drawn before the line is even read (and thus, in particular, before
>   any `\onslide` command can be read). However, placing a `\pause` or
>   `\uncover` at the end of the line before is also not helpful since it
>   will then suppress the horizontal line below the last uncovered line.

(Then comes an example showing a possible way to uncover tables.)

With the new edit to the original question:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
  \onslide<1->{a & b & c & d}
\onslide<2->{
  \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 1}
  \\
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 2 left}
  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Line 2 right} \\\hline
}
\onslide<3->{\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 1}
   \\ 
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Line 2 left}
  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Line 2 right} \\\hline
}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The end of the second row is inside `\onslide<2>`, so `\onslide<3>` doesn't see it on time; add a new line with a negative spacing at the beginning of the row, as my example shows.

Comment: Thanks... but the problem is that I have `\\ \hline` afterwards, your solution gives an extra line. If I keep your solution and remove the \\ before `\hline`, it does not compile well.

Comment: @SoftTimur that's no problem; see my updated answer for the solution (using `\\\hline` *inside* `\only`.)

Comment: Well, that is better, but what follows `\onslide<2->` is actually `\onslide<3->`. It seems that without `\\\hline` or \\ in the beginning of `\onslide<3->`, it doesn't compile, but it results in an extra line... I have added the code which does not work in OP...

Comment: @SoftTimur see my updated answer.

Comment: @SoftTimur it's all part of the problem with lines in a table that I mentioned; a better approach would be to consider not using lines in your tables if you are going to use overlays.

Comment: Thanks, just one more question, is the `2.8ex` the exact or approximate height of \\?

Comment: @SoftTimur it is an approximate value; I don't remember right now the exact length.

Comment: @SoftTimur I remembered the exact length (`\normalbaselineskip`):I've incorporated it to my edited anser.